# Creating a list of buttons dynamically in code

Tags: unity, c#, gui

I have a list of contacts. I need to create a scrollable list of buttons that are created dynamically so I can add each contact name as the button text. How would I do this all in code? My biggest concern is making sure the sizes stay consistent. I haven't had to do that in code before.

EDIT:

[image]

[image]

And here is the code to add the buttons to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    if (i > 0)
        crt.sizeDelta = new Vector2(crt.sizeDelta.x, crt.sizeDelta.y + initHeight);
    GameObject contactButton = Instantiate(Resources.Load("Contact Button")) as GameObject;
    contactButton.transform.parent = contactsList.transform;
    contactButton.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = names[i];
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

`ScrollRectHolder` holds `ScrollRect` component. The content of it is `ScrollContent`. Add `Vertical Layout Group` component on `ScrollContent`. It's also the parent of the buttons that will be instantiated each time you need. `Button` is the button prefab that will be instantiated. The variable `initialHeight` is the initial height of `ScrollContent`. Have to get it from `Rect Transform` of `ScrollContent`. Need to update `sizeDelta` with adding `initialHeight` whenever you add a new button.

```
public void AddNewButton()
{
 mRect.sizeDelta = new Vector2(mRect.sizeDelta.x, mRect.sizeDelta.y + initialHeight);
 GameObject gO = Instantiate(buttonPrefab);
 gO.transform.parent = transform;
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[unitypackage with scene, script and prefab.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B34Ar7u93rDULVZXSzEzeW1fcG8) Unity 5.2.4f1.

Comment: I gave this a shot but for some reason the buttons show up at the top left of the ScrollContent and are very small. I have the width and height constraint of the Vertical Layout Group turned off. Turning either on just makes the buttons way bigger than the screen. Any ideas?

Comment: check how `ScrollRectHolder`, `ScrollContent` are placed and anchored in edit. Last one is output.

Comment: I don't have a button already set in the ScrollContent since I am trying to create them all dynamically as I get the names. Will that be an issue? I have the ScrollContent size set to the same size as the prefab button is but the buttons still show up as tiny dots when they are created. They are automatically set to width: 10 and height: 10 for some reason. It says "some values driven by VerticalLayoutGroup"

Comment: If you want to keep the `ScrollContent` empty then ignore `sizeDelta` update first time or change `initial Height` dynamically. Most of the variable fields of `Rect Transform` are open to change runtime. Once your setup is right, there shouldn't be any problem. Share some shots of your current setup.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I have attached some screenshots and some code to the question for you.

Comment: @saboehnke not clear if it's working or not for you? have not tested. looks like should be working.

Comment: I have added another screenshot showing what it looks like in the scene once I run it. Basically it puts the contact buttons in, but they show up so small that you can't see them. In the screenshot you can see the small dots at the top left of the ScrollContent. No matter the size of the prefab buttons, these buttons are added and the sizes are changed to 10 x 10.

Comment: It's most probably because of you moved RectContent upward instead if keeping it in center where it's anchored. Can't test now, out of town for a week.

Comment: I went ahead and recreated the ScrollContent and didn't move it and the buttons appear in the center now so that is good. The only issue now is that the sizes are still not what they should be. They are 100 x 100 when my prefab is 160 x 80. This is making them overlap.

Comment: Have you had a chance to check this out?

Comment: Package added on edit. It's safe and easy to keep it not empty. Or you have to control the heights from script.

Comment: Check this out: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-LayoutElement.html